# RAM Usage in TeamCity

Tags: teamcity

We have a large TeamCity Server (10.0.3), with around 2.000 builds configurations and around 50 build agents.

Frequently, we encounter some performances issues, with a garbage collection.
Inside the `teamcity-server.log`, we found this:

```
[2017-11-28 12:30:54,339]   WARN -   jetbrains.buildServer.SERVER - GC usage exceeded 50% threshold and is now 60%. GC was fired 82987 times since server start and consumed total 18454595ms. Current memory usage: 1.09 GB.
```

We are unable to figure out the source of the issue.

According to the [Documentation](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Installing+and+Configuring+the+TeamCity+Server#InstallingandConfiguringtheTeamCityServer-SettingUpMemorysettingsforTeamCityServer), a 64 bit version of Java should be used, with only 4g RAM. We encountered some issues, and decided to use -Xmx6g parameter instead.

Do you know where we can enable/find more traces in order to figure out the source of our over-consumption of memory ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can try disabling third-party plugins and see if it helps.

Then you try benchmarking the server according to [this blog post](https://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2015/08/benchmarking-teamcity/) and see if increased memory limits will improve the situations.

But the best way to investigate the memory over-consumption would be capturing the memory dump and investigating the content using profiling tools. You can create memory dump from **Administration | Server Administration | Diagnostics** page of your TeamCity web UI using **Dump Memory Snapshot** button.

You can investigate the dump on your own or send it to Jetbrains for investigation.